# How do I delete an answer which is link only?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

There is this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/223795/237) that is only a link. patrix has left a standard comment

> Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone

If this was on a low quality queue I could vote to delete.

However the wording for low quality flag is

> This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

Well these link only questions are obviously fixable by editing the information in so this is not a valid flag

The not an answer flag says

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

These links are surely delete altogether. So  this is the obvious flag to use. but as in this question these flags are rejected.

How do I get the answer deleted as link only - I know this is the thing that is needed,

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up.

Answer (score 1):

I've declined the flag with "flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer". May be a borderline case, but usually I try to refrain from deleting an answer even if it doesn't directly answer the question. In this case the key issue is that it is link-only, the linked project most probably seems to offer an alternative to the tool the asker is using to run WhatsApp. Which, in my eyes, makes it an answer with quality issues, but not necessarily something I would want to delete.

Let's look at the two flags which could be applied here:

> This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

While I agree that it has severe problems in its current form, the question seems salvageable through editing (basically by just summarizing the README.me found on Github).

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

It definitively is an attempt to answer the question (or in this case rather the question behind the question), even it doesn't directly address the problem described.

Comment: But if in Low quality queue would be an automatic choice to delete. I don't see any possibility of a choice here either it is link only or it has other info than a link (An issue here is there is no way to flag the author to tell them to expand the answer without flag for low quality) and rejected flags impact me so the unclear areas seem poor

Comment: I've expanded my answer a bit. The usual way to notify users is actually to comment/down vote.

Comment: and that is the issue - the flags don't seem reasonable - but the delete reason is obvious and seems to be an absolute decision is it just a link or not - how do I get to it reliably - given your comment re the LQ flag the delete option should not be on the LQ queue

Comment: Typical LQ queue entries include "I have this problem, too" and "Apple is crap" postings, which definitively are candidates for deletion.

Comment: I meant delete as is just a link which is the option in the LQ queue

Comment: Yes, deletion is an option in the LQ queue, but IMHO this doesn't imply that every queue entry is a candidate for deletion.

Comment: So, just to double check, the policy on Ask Different is to not to follow the standard SE policy that link-only answers are NAA? References: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370) and [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231)

Comment: @Makyen Sites are free to set their own rules. I‘m not sure there is a big difference anyway, at least not to the two questions you‘ve linked to. A link-only answer usually is not a good answer and needs editing, but as long as the linked information is relevant to the question it brings the topic forward (which is what we are looking for). Also, users are more likely to feel welcome if we help them to improve their answers and not just delete things they contributed

Comment: I didn't argue for or against any policy here. I only asked for clarification that you were knowingly and intentionally choosing to adopt a policy for this site which is contrary to what the rest of the SE network uses. Frankly, if you are doing so, I'd suggest that you make that crystal clear to everyone. You talk about being welcoming. Doing the opposite of what other sites on the network do alienates those people who come here from other SE sites, particularly when they are not informed of what policies are contrary to their expectations, in advance of them experiencing the contradiction.

Comment: @mayken Let me look at the two links again, at first glance I didn‘t read them as „all link only answers must be deleted“

Comment: @mayken See https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1629/why-was-my-flag-for-not-an-answer-decline, https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2801/should-we-flag-different-on-ask-different, and, well, my answer above, on how link-only answers are treated on AD and the rationale behind. In a nutshell: The community here puts more emphasis on improving a (relevant) link-only answer into something useful than in outright deletion.

Comment: @mayken Ah, wasn't aware of the context of your comment, caught up with the comments in Charcoal HQ in the meantime. Establishing a clear policy might be the topic for a new Meta Q/A, but basically we tend to give a poster time to improve the answer instead of outright deleting it. And links to support.apple.com are usually not understood as link-only because any summarization made in the answer will be outdated as soon as Apple updates the support article (which happens quite a lot).

Comment: @nohillside I just stumbled upon this post as a result of figuring out why my NAA flag [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/440880) was declined. This answer does suggest that NAA flags on such link-only answers may get declined. However, the [FAQ on NAA flags](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1629) indicates that the standard SE policy is also in effect on AD, as per the latest [revision](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/1630/9). This answer, and the FAQ, appear to be in conflict. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @cigien the last paragraph of https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1630/9058 sums it up nicely: if the answer has issues which you as a user can fix yourself, please go ahead and do so. Basically any user is a moderator here after all, most issues can be fixed without the few additional rights elected mods have.

Comment: @nohillside I'm afraid I don't see how a regular user (or a moderator for that matter) could fix this particular answer. I think I'll go ahead and post a new question on meta seeking clarification on the policy, as doing so in the comments is likely to get unwieldy.

Comment: @cigien It is an attempt to answer the question. Most likely an unsuccessful one, but then flags should be used to flag incorrect or wrong answers. Just downvote and move on.